# How to elegantly check null check for java method parameter?

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, hardcoded

How to elegantly check null check for java method parameter?

I have code like this:

```
    public void updateAccount(String a, int b, double c, float d, List e, Set f, Map g, Collection h, Enum i ...String) {
        if(a != null && !a.isBlank()) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        if(b != null && !b.isBlank()) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        if(c != null && !c.isBlank()) {
            this.c = c;
        }
        if(d != null && !d.isBlank()) {
            this.d = d;
        }
        if(e != null && !e.isBlank()) {
            this.e = e;
        }
        if(f != null && !f.isBlank()) {
            this.f = f;
        }
        if(g != null && !g.isBlank()) {
            this.g = g;
        }
        if(h != null && !h.isBlank()) {
            this.h = h;
        }if(i != null && !i.isBlank()) {
            this.i = i;
        }
        ....
    }
```

All parameters are checked for null, and if not null, the value of the corresponding field is changed.

I feel that the above method is too hard-coded.

I'm wondering how I can turn this into more efficient code.

Best Regards!

Comment: I like to use `Optional`s: `this.a = Optional.ofNullable(a).filter(not(String::isBlank)).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);`

Comment: @Turing85 that doesn't eliminate the necessity of having one line per parameter, which I think is what bothers OP. Also note that the behavior they're looking for is not set-or-throw but rather set-or-ignore, so rather `orElse(this.a)`

Comment: Well in this case... the only other possibility I see would be annotation-based bean validation. This, however, would require a framework that supports bean validation.

Comment: You could write setter-methods for each attribute and make the checks there.

Comment: Note that your example is doing `null` checks on `int`, `float`, `double`, etc and calling `isBlank()` on reference types that don't support that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can do null checks for the parameters using the following ways:

use [@NonNull](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) annotation from [project lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull).
For more information please refer to lombok documentation.

If you are using frameworks like [Spring framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNull.html) then Spring has an [@NotNull](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNull.html) annotation that leverages JSR-305 standard.

If you don't want to use any of the above solutions then you can as well using Optional.ofNullable() starting from java 8. You can check more about Optional class at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html